# PDO case exist not working with bind parameters

Tags: mysql, pdo, case, exists

I am checking if a username and password combination exist in either table?

I am doing this in PDO using bind parameters. When the page is executed it shows an error: `currently unable to handle this request.`

Here is my code:

```
    $stmtus = $conn->prepare("Select
                case
                when exists (
                Select 1 from School_Profile 
                where aes_decrypt(SchoolEmail, 'SALT') = :Username  and password = :Password
                ) then 'Admin'
                when exists (
                Select 1 from NonAdminUsers 
                where aes_decrypt(Nuser, 'SALT') = :Username and Npassword = :Password
                ) then 'Non Admin'
                else 'Unknown'
                end result");
 $stmtus->bindParam(':Username', $username);
 $stmtus->bindParam(':Password', $password);
 $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
 $stmtus -> execute();
```

My error log shows:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in`

Comment: Don't use `htmlspecialchars` on data going into the database. That is going to cause you problems later on. Use `htmlspecialchars` when you output in HTML context only.

Comment: @Dharman. Thank you for the advise. I will change it. Can you tell me what type of issues I might run into?

Comment: What if you would like to output data to another medium? What if you wanted to search the data in the DB? What if you would like to modify the saved information. You can't do that if your data is preformatted for HTML

Comment: Could you show us how you open the PDO connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't reuse a named parameter more than once, which is likely the source of your error.  So, for a quick workaround, just don't use the same parameter twice or more:

```
$stmtus = $conn->prepare("SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT 1 FROM School_Profile
             WHERE AES_DECRYPT(SchoolEmail, 'SALT') = :user1 AND password = :pass1)
         THEN 'Admin'
         WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT 1 FROM NonAdminUsers
             WHERE AES_DECRYPT(Nuser, 'SALT') = :user2 AND Npassword = :pass2)
         THEN 'Non Admin'
         ELSE 'Unknown'
         END result");

$stmtus->bindParam(':user1', $username);
$stmtus->bindParam(':pass1', $password);
$stmtus->bindParam(':user2', $username);
$stmtus->bindParam(':pass2', $password);
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$stmtus->execute();
```